# JBoss Context Parameter

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

i've a simple Servlet that "serve" a simple XML file; it would be dynamic loaded from a file. In tomcat I use a Context Parameter, how can I do in JBoss ?

Code:

```
resp.setContentType("text/xml");
// String path = System.getProperty("AnagraficaXML");
String path = getServletContext().getInitParameter("AnagraficaXML");
// InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(XML_FILE);
File file = new File(path);
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    out.append(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
br.close();
fileReader.close();
```

Tomcat configuration ( file server.xml )

```
<Context docBase="AnagraficaCedacri" path="/AnagraficaCedacri"
    reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AnagraficaCedacri">
    <Parameter name="AnagraficaXML" value="D:\Dvlpmnts\Cedacri\CedacriServerResources\Anagrafica.xml"
        override="false" />
</Context>
```

I would find a "portable" solution that could work in Tomcat / Jboss & WebSpehere !

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a Java web application (WAR) and put it in the deployments folder.

```
@WebServlet("/AnagraficaCedacri")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
         throws ServletException, IOException {

      resp.setContentType("text/xml");
      // String path = System.getProperty("AnagraficaXML");
      String path = getServletContext().getInitParameter("AnagraficaXML");
      // InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(XML_FILE);
      File file = new File(path);
      FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
      PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
      String line = br.readLine();
      while (line != null) {
         out.append(line);
         line = br.readLine();
      }
      br.close();
      fileReader.close();    
   }
}
```

More information at: http://hudson.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS7-Docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/guides/developer-getting-started-guide/target/docbook/publish/en-US/html/helloworld.html

hope this helps.
Oliver